# ASP_MVC5 - ANGULAR - Shared Variable with provider

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, razor

I'm about ASP net coupled with angularjs.
I have a  main layout and 2 content pages
I want to spend my globals variables in page1 to page2.
I use a provider to pass the variable.
here's my problem: I just can not get a variable in my page2.

my layout page :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Mon application ASP.NET</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body ng-app="MainApp">
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/MyScripts/MainApp.js"></script>
    <script src="~/MyScripts/Page1Ctrl.js"></script>
    <script src="~/MyScripts/Page2Ctrl.js"></script>
    <script src="~/MyScripts/GlobalParam.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

my page 1:

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "¨Page1";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<div ng-controller="Page1Ctrl">
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="passVariable('5')">Pass variable (5)  to Page2 with provider</a></p>
</div>
```

My page 2 :

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "¨Page2";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>


<div ng-controller="Page2Ctrl">

    <label>received value : {{reveiveValue}}</label>

</div>
```

my main APP :

```js
var MainApp = angular.module('MainApp',
    [
        'Page1App',
        'Page2App',
        'GlobalParam'
    ]);
```

My pageCtrl1:

```js
'use strict';
var Page1App = angular.module('Page1App', ['GlobalParam'])
Page1App.controller('Page1Ctrl', function ($scope, $window, Param) {
    $scope.passVariable = function (val) {
        $scope.shared = val;
        $window.location.href = '/Home/Page2';
    }
})
```

My pageCtrl2 :

```js
'use strict';
var Page2App = angular.module('Page2App', ['GlobalParam'])
Page2App.controller('Page2Ctrl', function ($scope, Param) {
    $scope.reveiveValue = Param.value;
})
```

My service :

```js
angular.module('GlobalParam', [])
    .provider('Param', [function () {
        this.$get = ['$http', '$q',
            function ($http, $q) {
                return {
                    value:0
                };
            }];
    }])
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are doing a server side redirect:

```
$window.location.href = '/Home/Page2';
```

which obviously will perform a roundtrip to the server and a full page reload. This will kill any javascript/angular stuff you might have done. So if you want to pass some variable during a server side redirect you can use query string parameters:

```
$scope.passVariable = function (val) {
    $window.location.href = '/Home/Page2?myVariable=' + encodeURIComponent(val);
}
```

and in your target view you can render this variable using the server side Razor template:

```
<label>received value : @Request["myVariable"]</label>
```

And if you wanted to retrieve the value of this server side variable on the client you may create some global variable in your template:

```
<script>
    window.myVariable = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Request["myVariable"]));
</script>
```

And then use `window.myVariable` where needed in your scripts.

If on the other hand you want to have a SPA application then you should not be doing any server side redirects. You may consider in this case using [angular ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which allows you to pass variables during **client side** redirects (redirects that modify only the fragment portion of the url - `#`).

Comment: Oh! thank you a lot, I understands.
I will test with ui-route and coming back to you later.
I want a SPA Application

Comment: OK, so if you want a SPA application you should definitely checkout the ui-router and have a very *slim* MVC controller that only serves a single view which will be the host for your SPA application. Then your SPA application can make asynchronous calls to a server side API to fetch data.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnetcurry/SPA-Angularjs-ASPNET-WebAPI/tree/master/MVC_Using_Angular.

Comment: I test the code in this link above, and this is a problem that I not include:
If I'm at: http: // localhost: 11111 / showemployees
And if I refreshed the page F5 (by chance or carelessness), I get  the below error: 
Erreur du serveur dans l'application '/'.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hard to say how you can solve this problem. It appears that your server is throwing some error. You may consider looking at the logs or debugging your code to see the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little test.
why I'm always redirected to the server?

Main HTML :

```html
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>MainApp</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="~/MyScripts/MainApp.js"></script>
    <script src="~/MyScripts/Page1Ctrl.js"></script>
    <script src="~/MyScripts/Page2Ctrl.js"></script>
    <script src="~/MyScripts/GlobalParam.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="MainApp">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="Page1">Page1</a></li>
        <li><a href="Page2">Page2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

MainApp.js

```js
var MainApp = angular.module('MainApp', ["ngRoute"]);
MainApp.factory("ShareData", function () {
    return { value: 0 }
});

//Defining Routing
MainApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/Page1',
                        {
                            templateUrl: 'Home/Page1',
                            controller: 'Page1Ctrl'
                        });
    $routeProvider.when('/Page2',
                        {
                            templateUrl: 'Home/Page2',
                            controller: 'Page2Ctrl'
                        });

    // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')
}]);
```

Controlleur ASP :

```js
    public class HomeController : Controller {


        public ActionResult MainApp() {
            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult Page1() {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Page2() {

            return View();
        }

    }
```